# Assertion Failed error while trying to create a substring

Tags: c, string, malloc, assertions, strcpy

I'm trying to write my own function in order to substring a given pointer to chars array, by a given length and start index.

When I execute the code, i'm getting an error **"Debug Assertion Failed"**. The program failes in **"tcscpy_s.inl" (Expression: L"Buffer is too small" && 0)**

This is my code:

```
char* String_Substring(char* OriginalString, int StartIndex, int Length)
{
    // Allocate space for the new string by it's given length.
    char* StrToRet = (char*)malloc((Length + 1) * sizeof(char));

    // Move to the start position of the sub - string.
    OriginalString += StartIndex;

    // Copy the requested sub - string to 'StrToRet'
    strcpy_s(StrToRet, Length, OriginalString);

    return StrToRet;
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you certain that the bug arises in this code segment?  Have you verified that the memory actually gets allocated?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but technically your malloc should be `(Length + 1) * sizeof(char)`.

Comment: @chuex You are right, I changed it.

Answer (score 2):

The buffer size does not include space for terminating `0` (although allocation is done correctly). Try

```
strcpy_s(StrToRet, Length + 1, OriginalString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try allocate more memory for StrToRet.
Make shure that StartIndex and Length non-negative number and OriginalString correct null terminated string.